# Utilizar AVI no componente TAnimate (projeto VCL)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, animação

Utilizo o Delphi 7 e estou há mais de 4 horas tentando adicionar uma simples animação "carregando" (loading) em um componente TAnimate, sem sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao tentar carregar o arquivo AVI através da propriedade `FileName` do componente TAnimate recebo a mensagem `"Cannot open AVI"`. Por favor, qual o tipo de AVI é compatível com esse componente?

Para testar, criei uma animação GIF através do site https://loading.io e depois fiz a conversão em AVI pelo https://convertio.co. Para a conversão removi o áudio e tentei diversas configurações de codec, sem codec nenhum, com codecs antigos (ex: WMV1), mas nada funcionou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor, alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?

Obrigado!!

Comment: Ja tentou `uses ShellAnimations` ?

Comment: @David, infelizmente o Delphi 7 não possui essa unit...

Comment: Encontrei outro [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788039/gif-to-avi-with-windows-animate-control) do StackOverflow (em inglês) sobre o mesmo problema e consegui resolver seguindo as instruções. Baixei um aplicativo trial chamado _Jasc Animation Shop_ que fez a conversão de GIF para AVI sem nenhuma codificação, e consegui carregar normalmente no componente `TAnimate`.

Comment: Quem bom, obrigado por compartilhar :)